# UIApplicationShortcutItem - Can I use an image downloaded from the web as UIApplicationShortcutIcon?

Tags: ios, 3dtouch

I'm setting up some 3D Touch functionality and would like to use an image that has been downloaded from the web (can access via `SDWebImage`'s cache) as an audio cover image in a `UIApplicationShortcutItem`, just like Apple's music app (see screenshot).

[image: Apple Music screenshot]

Is this possible? It looks like it isn't as I can't put the image in to the app's bundle as far as I know? I guess Apple is doing something that devs can't do yet?

`UIApplicationShortcutItem`'s docs only have the following:

```
// Create an icon using a system-defined image.
+ (instancetype)iconWithType:(UIApplicationShortcutIconType)type;

// Create an icon from a custom image.
// The provided image named will be loaded from the app's bundle
// and will be masked to conform to the system-defined icon style.
+ (instancetype)iconWithTemplateImageName:(NSString *)templateImageName;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct. It is not currently possible (at least with the public API) for third-party apps to use a non-template image, nor is it possible to download an image and use it as the `UIApplicationShortcutIcon`. If you would like to see these abilities added in a future release, please consider filing an enhancement request at [bugreport.apple.com](http://bugreport.apple.com).