# UIApplicationShortcutIconType.Contact shows the refresh icon on xamarin.iOS in navigation bar

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm developing an iOS app with Xamarin.iOS.

I'm trying to put a contact icon in my Navigationitem. According to the Apple developer docs(https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/system-icons/) you have to use `UIApplicationShortcutIconType.Contact`.

When i'm using this I get the reply icon in my navigation bar.

[Reply icon in navigation bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jdr7d.png)

And it should be this:
[Contact icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BB5eX.png)

Here's my code:

```
NavigationItem.Title = "Menu";
        NavigationItem.HidesBackButton = true;
        var contactbutton = (UIBarButtonSystemItem)UIApplicationShortcutIconType.Contact;
        NavigationItem.RightBarButtonItem = new UIBarButtonItem(contactbutton);
        NavigationController.NavigationBarHidden = false;
```

Does anyone have an idea what's the problem in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you read from the documentation the `UIApplicationShortcutIconType` is **Home Screen Quick Action Icons** used for 3D touch shortcuts. We can not use it for **Navigation Bar and Toolbar Icons** as `UIBarButtonSystemItem`.

If you do want to use system style. You can only try `UIBarButtonSystemItem` [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibarbuttonsystemitem).

Also you can see the thread below. It posts some references we can't do this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43063432/8354952